# Leaflet: bring the marker to front when click

Tags: javascript, leaflet

is there a method that bring the marker to front? the zoomMarker is the details of markers and when details is clicked, **(the max zoom is 11 so the markers is nearer to each other and the label cant read)** it will panTo, but since the max zoom is 11, it cant see where there is so much marker. *(this is a leaflet windy map, thats why the max zoom is only 11)*

```
$("#mapContainer").on("click",".zoomMarker",function(){
    var zoom;
    var zoomValueIn;
    var no = $(this).attr("mapNo");
    var deviceID = $(this).attr("deviceID");

    var events = findMapNo(no).eventData[deviceID].events;
    findMapNo(no).map.setZoom(19);

    if( events.length>0 ){
        var eventsIndex = findMapNo(no).eventData[deviceID].events.length-1;
        var temp_content = createPopupContent(deviceID, eventsIndex, no);
        var lat = events[events.length-1][4];
        var lng = events[events.length-1][3];
        var latLng = new L.latLng(lat, lng);

        findMapNo(no).map.setZoom(19);
        var Oldzoom = findMapNo(no).map.getZoom();

        popup = L.popup({
            permanent: true,
            autoPan: false,
            minWidth: 200,
            closeOnClick: true,
            minHeight: 200,
            offset: [0, -12]})
            .setLatLng(latLng)
            .setContent(temp_content);

        if(Oldzoom == Oldzoom){
            findMapNo(no).map.removeLayer(markersCluster);
            findMapNo(no).map.addLayer(markersLayer); 
            findMapNo(no).map.panTo(latLng); 
            //should bring to front the marker
            if(findMapNo(no).map.hasLayer(markersLayer)){
                findMapNo(no).map.openPopup(popup);
            }
        }

        findMapNo(no).map.on("zoomend", function (e) {
            zoom = this.getZoom();
            var diff = Oldzoom - zoom; 
            if(diff > 0 || diff < 0){ 
                if(diff > 0){
                    findMapNo(no).map.closePopup(popup);
                }else{  
                    if(zoom == zoom){
                        if(diff < 0){ 
                            diff = diff - 1;
                        }else if(diff > 0){
                            diff = diff + 1;
                        }else if(diff == 0){ 
                            //should bring to front the marker
                            findMapNo(no).map.panTo(latLng); 
                            findMapNo(no).map.openPopup(popup);
                        } 
                    }
                    Oldzoom = zoom;
                    //should bring to front the marker
                    findMapNo(no).map.removeLayer(markersCluster);
                }
                findMapNo(no).map.removeLayer(markersLayer);
                findMapNo(no).map.addLayer(markersCluster);
            } 

            Oldzoom = zoom;            
        });
    }else{
        toaster("Marker No Location","warning");
    }
});
```

Comment: Please - provide Your code. It's not easy to help right now

Comment: @AdamKniec i edited the codes already

Answer (score 2):

You can use the option `riseOnHover` by mouseover the marker comes to front.

```
var marker = L.marker([lat,lng], {riseOnHover: true});      
marker.addTo(map);
```

I had the same question. I read that the Markers has no bringToFront() option, because they are  directed by north to south. A Marker more in the north are on the top